# Get default user data directory in Node.js

Tags: node.js, appdata

I have a NPM project that I need to save some JSON files of the settings of the user to be re-used on a restart. However, I want these settings to work across all projects the user has made. Is there a way to get the default  user dir, cross-platform? I am only familiar with Windows 10, but I know for my version the data should be stored under:
`C:Users\divinelemon\AppData\Roaming`

What are the defaults for others like Ubuntu or Mac Os?

How would I programmatically get this default in Node.js?